# Check if string is like regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a folder of many applications that are used for deployment on laptops or workstations. Now this folder is becoming a big mess because multiple people use this folder and everyone uses a different storage method. Therefore I wanted to write a script that helps manage the files in a way we can always find them.

In Powershell I want to.

1. List all the files (.msi, .exe, and maybe more)
2. Determine if the files are correctly stored already (Developer\Application\Application_version_architecture.extension ie. Adobe\Flashplayer\Flashplayer_22_x64.msi)
3. If true, leave it.
4. If not, I question the user of the script
       some things about the application so the script then renames and
       moves it to the correct folder.

Currently I'm stuck on step 2. I want to use a regex where I determine what the standard should be. However, it keeps ruling out applications that are correctly named.

I use the following command to retrieve the filenames:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Name
```

This retrieves the files in the application folder with complete path like
**"Adobe\Flashplayer\Flashplayer_22_x64.msi"**
Or when incorrect
**"Adobe\flashplayeractivex.msi"**

I then use the following regex to check if they are correct or incorrect

```
\w*\\\w*\\[a-zA-Z]*\_[0-9a-zA-Z\.]*\_(([x][6][4])|([x][8][6])|([b|B][o][t][h]))\.(([m|M][s|S][i|I])|([e|E][x|X][e|E]))
```

Which I have confirmed working on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/).
However, I cannot get it working with powershell. I've tried the following:

```
if ($file -match '\w*\\\w*\\[a-zA-Z]*\_[0-9a-zA-Z\.]*\_(([x][6][4])|([x][8][6])|([b|B][o][t][h]))\.(([m|M][s|S][i|I])|([e|E][x|X][e|E]))') {......commands...}
```

Which does not seem to work because of the escapes (Powershell threw some errors at me). I then tried:

```
$pattern = [regex]::Escape('\w*\\\w*\\[a-zA-Z]*\_[0-9a-zA-Z\.]*\_(([x][6][4])|([x][8][6])|([b|B][o][t][h]))\.(([m|M][s|S][i|I])|([e|E][x|X][e|E]))')
if ($file -match $pattern) {......commands...}
```

Which didn't gave me errors, but did not work because it didn't "match" "Apple\iTunes\iTunes_12.3_x64.exe" which does match on Rubular.

Does anyone recognize this problem or see what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try all this in a single regex. Instead I would check each policy individually:

```
$path = 'C:\tmp'
$validExtensions = @('.msi', '.exe')
$filnameRegex = '\w+_[0-9a-zA-Z\.]+_(?:x32|x64|[b|B]oth)'

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if (-not ($_.Extension -cin $validExtensions))
    {
        Write-Host "$($_.FullName) has an invalid extension."
    }
    if (-not ($_.BaseName -match $filnameRegex))
    {
        Write-Host "$($_.FullName) doesn't match the filename policy."
    }

   if (3 -ne ($_.FullName.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar).Length `
    - $path.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar).Length))
    {
        Write-Host "$($_.FullName) doesn't match the directory policy."
    }
}
```